# Static google maps coordinates differ in different browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps, coordinates

I have a problem with positioning my embedded google maps correctly. At first, I used the premade embed code from google itself, but it keps showing my Marker off-screen. I started fiddling with the `ll` attribute coordinates and managed to center the marker in my screen.

But for some reason, the map is still shown wrongly on IE (only happens on some PCs, haven't been able to reproduce on all PCs). While in Chrome and FF the map is centered correctly, IE shows the marker in the far right bottom corner. What could possibly cause this?

```
<iframe width="680" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" 
marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/mapsq=Gierlebaan+56+2460+Tielen
&hl=nl&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Gierlebaan+56,+2460+Kasterlee,+Antwerpen,+Vlaams+Gewest,
+Belgi%C3%AB&t=m&z=14&vpsrc=0&ll=51.253965,4.862394&output=embed"></iframe>
```

On Chrome / FF:
[image]

On IE:
[image]

This is the live site (visit the Contact page) for testing purposes: http://anjawynants.be/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by refreshing the source whenever the map appears:

```
$("iframe")[0].src = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Gierlebaan+56+2460+Tielen&hl=nl&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Gierlebaan+56,+2460+Kasterlee,+Antwerpen,+Vlaams+Gewest,+Belgi%C3%AB&t=m&z=14&vpsrc=0&output=embed&iwloc=near";
```

The issue was possibly caused by the PC/connection/browser speed, which determined whether the map completed loading before or after I `hide()` it.